# Array Json Deserialization Issues in C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

```
string uri = Application.Current.Properties["Uri"].ToString();
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetAsync(uri + "/products");
var resultparsing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductResponse>(await 
result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(resultparsing.products.ToString());
```

The code running, Deserialization issue coming from listtostring when the resultparsing is passing just the object name which in this case it just saying it is a list and not passing the list itself to var list when it attempts to fetch the items.

```
public class Item
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProductResponse
    {
        public string count { get; set; }
        public List<Item> products { get; set; }
    }
```

Examples of Json that is initially being captured

```
{"count":2,"products":[{"name":"item","location":"storeroom","_id":"6219602068c9a900043fe844"},{"name":"item2","location":"storeroom","_id":"6219603768c9a900043fe850"}]}
```

Comment: it would help immensely if you posted a sample of your json and the three C# classes you are attempting to deserialize.  Generally you do not need to deserialize the same string multiple times, which makes me think you either have a very unusual json structure, or you misunderstand how deserialization works

Comment: @Jason Apologies, I have went and restructured my question and added in the classes that are being referenced in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to deserialize once

```
var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductResponse>(json);
```

`resp` is a `ProductResponse` object that should contain all of the product detail in the `products` property.  You do not need to deserialize products separately